# How to make a Google Charts pie-chart change size according to the data being passed to it?

Tags: javascript, c#, charts, google-visualization

I want to have three pie charts and each chart will be one slice so to speak, as only one piece of data will be passed to it. So for e.g. one pie chart will be the number of cars bought this month, the next chart will have the number of cars bought last month, and the final chart will have the total number of cars bought this year. If the number of cars bought this month is 1200 and the number of cars bought last month is 2000 then I want this to be reflected in the size of the pie chart. I know it ties into the

```
width: and height:
```

in the configuration options, I'm just not sure how to apply this dynamically, as it will change on a daily basis etc.

I have considered using one pie-chart but the use of three separate charts will suit the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any of your code or explanation of how you are using the google chart API. But from javascript you should have an options object like this:

```
var options = {'title':'Number of Cars',
                 'width':todaysWidth,
                 'height':todaysHeight,
                 legend: 'none'
  };
```

Just set the width and height to the values you want and then draw the chart:

```
myChart.draw(data,options);
```

where `myChart` is an instance of the google.visualization pie chart class. When the values change, just make the changes to the `options` object and then call `myChart.draw(data,options);` again.

So a function that would update this could be:

```
function updateChart(newHeight,newWidth,myChart){
    var options={'title':'Number of Cars',
        'height':newHeight,
        'width':newWidth,
        legend:'none'
    }
    myChart.draw(data,options);
}
```

and so whenever the data changes you'd call `updateChart(...);` with the appropriate height, width, and chart as arguments.

Comment: Thanks very much, I haven't any code yet as I'm planning it out and reading up Google Charts docs. So could `todaysWidth` be tied to the value of the data to update the chart size dynamically?

Comment: yeah. I've updated to show how you'd do it. Also note you can clear the old chart with `myChart.clearChart();` but in my experience it seems to work if you skip this and just use the `draw` method as above.